# What am I missing here? JS code

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, dreamweaver, underscore.js

For some reason this code is throwing a syntax error on line 5. What am I missing here? Help please!

```
<script type="text/template" id="question-template">
    <h1 class="headline"><%= title %></h1>
    <h2 class="subheadline"><%= question %></h2>
    <ul class="answers">
        <% _.each( answers, function( answer ) { %>
          <% if (answer.type == "input") { %>
          <li>
            <input type="number" placeholder="<%= answer.title %>">
          </li>
          <% }else{ %>
          <li><a class="answer" href="#question/<%= id+1 %>" <% if (typeof(answer.callback) !== "undefined") { %>onclick="<%= answer.callback %>"<% } %>>
            <%= answer.title %></a>
        </li>
          <% } %>
        <% }); %>
    </ul>
</script>
```

Comment: What template engine are you using here?

Comment: What is the error? Are you using underscore.js? Did you remember to include that library?

Comment: Just throwing a general syntax error in dreamweaver. Yes underscore is included. Guy coded this for me but can't get a hold of him.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/zepto.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/underscore.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/backbone.min.js"></script>

Comment: DreamWeaver is complaining but the browser isn't? The template looks okay so perhaps DreamWeaver is ignoring the `type` and trying to interpret it as HTML or JavaScript.

Comment: It works, although it seems like a bad idea to have an onclick function defined in the model/template:  http://jsfiddle.net/zYdpb/3/.  I think mu is right.